# Color string in Angular html when supplied an array of offsets and length pairs of coloring places with overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, binary-tree, string-parsing

I.e. the following string 'violation buffer' has the following places it needs to apply coloring in html.

```
[
{ offsetFromStart : 3, length : 3},
{ offsetFromStart : 2, length : 6},
{ offsetFromStart : 4, length : 7},
{ offsetFromStart : 13, length : 3},
]
```

so the desired effect is

```
 v<span style="background-color:green">i<span style="background-color:red;">ola</span>tion bu</span>f<span style="background-color:blue">fe</span>r
```

What is the best approach in JS to achieve such effect?
I though about using some binary trees and then concatenate into single string but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but what is the desired effect?

Comment: was supposed to be spans tags in the string, v<span style="background-color:green">i<span style="background-color:red;">ola</span>tion bu</span>f<span style="background-color:blue">fe</span>r

Comment: @Badacadabra what do you think?